# Include data before contract deployment

Tags: solidity, snapshot

I'm creating an upgraded ERC20 token where I want to include the past owners (1,000+) holdings as a claimable amount.

What is the most appropriate way of getting that data into the contract?

1. Is there a way to insert it during contract initialization?
2. Should I make a mutative function that I call after the contract gets created
3. Should I use some sort of chain link to read from IPFS?

Any help / guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. migrate all data yourself. It will be expensive.
2. on-chain individual migrations, need some sort of control on the old contract so none can migrate the same tokens more than once,
3. off-chain migration, prepare a snapshot and use a merkle tree to claim tokens, uniswap did something similar for their airdrop.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Method IMO:

1. Deploy the Upgraded ERC20 with mint still allowed and an ownable module.
2. Deploy a contract to check the `balanceOf` of the previous ERC20 you deployed, and either burn or transfer the previous ERC20 token to a specific address (Recommend Zero Address). And then mint the equivalent amount of tokens in the Upgraded ERC20 to that user wallet.

This is comparatively less expensive to you while ensuring all the interested parties get their tokens. As an added, you can also put a time limit on the claim so that process is completed in your checklist. Once the claim is finished, you can revoke the claim contract's admin access and stop the mint once and for all (if that is what you want in the Upgraded ERC20).

I don't recommend adding the claim part in the Upgraded ERC20 itself, as that will not be useable after the claim is accomplished.

Comment: In a perfect world this is the correct answer. But this assumes the original ERC20 balanceOf is frozen somehow. Which, is not the case.